# Dealing with two selects to show/hide Divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've been racking my head for a while now, I'm starting to think there is no way of actually doing this,
Basically what I want to accomplish, Is so you can select from two dropdowns and they will show/hide divs but the selects need to work together.

Here is what I have so far below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.filter-case').on("change", function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == "default") {
            $(".systemfilter").css("display", "inline");
            $(".boxes").removeClass("systemfilter");
        } else {
            $(".boxes").addClass("systemfilter");
            $(".systemfilter").css("display", "none");
            $("."+value).css("display", "block");
        }
    });
    $('select.filter-case-locations').on("change", function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == "default") {    
            $(".location").css("display", "inline");
            $(".boxes").removeClass("location");
        } else {
            $(".boxes").addClass("location");
            $(".location").css("display", "none");
            $("."+value).css("display", "block");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="filter-case">

<option selected="" value="default">system</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system01">system01</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system02">system02</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system03">system03</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system04">system04</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system05">system05</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system06">system06</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system07">system07</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system08">system08</option>
</select>

<select class="filter-case-locations">
<option selected="" value="default">Location</option>
<option value="locaton_categories-essex">Essex</option>
<option value="locaton_categories-greenhithe">Kent</option>
<option value="locaton_categories-kent">Kent</option>
<option value="locaton_categories-london">London</option>
<option value="locaton_categories-sussex">Sussex</option>
</select>

<div class="boxes locaton_categories-essex system_categories-system04"><h3>Essex System04</div>
<div class="boxes locaton_categories-essex system_categories-system02"><h3>Essex System02</div>
<div class="boxes locaton_categories-greenhithe system_categories-system04"><h3>Essex System06</div>
<div class="boxes locaton_categories-greenhithe system_categories-system04"><h3>Essex System04</div>
<div class="boxes locaton_categories-london system_categories-system04"><h3>London System03</div>
```

I want the drop downs to work independently. I just can't think how to make it work. I added classes because I thought it might be possible, to do something with those, maybe work out a if statement, but I've got no where.

**Summery:**
What I Want is if someone selects **System 01** for example then selects **Kent**. It will show all the **system 01** in Kent. But if someone just selects a location and no system it still show all the locations.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I sat down, Had a cup of tea, cookies, And I realised id been the dumbest dev to have ever walked this earth.

I was using two drop downs but not using them in the same function ....
Once I realised that it was easy :D

```js
    $(function() {
        var $li = $('.case-wrap').find('li')
        $(".filter-case, .filter-case-locations").on("change", function() {
            var a = $(".filter-case").val();
            var b = $(".filter-case-locations").val();

            $li.hide().filter("." + a + '.' + b).show();

        }).change();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="filter-case">

<option selected="" value="default">system</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system01">system01</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system02">system02</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system03">system03</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system04">system04</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system05">system05</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system06">system06</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system07">system07</option>
  <option value="system_categories-system08">system08</option>
</select>

<select class="filter-case-locations">
<option selected="" value="default">Location</option>
<option value="locaton_categories-essex">Essex</option>
<option value="locaton_categories-greenhithe">Kent</option>
<option value="locaton_categories-kent">Kent</option>
<option value="locaton_categories-london">London</option>
<option value="locaton_categories-sussex">Sussex</option>
</select>
<ul class="case-wrap">
<li class="boxes default locaton_categories-essex system_categories-system04"><h3>Essex System04</li>
<li class="boxes default locaton_categories-essex system_categories-system02"><h3>Essex System02</li>
<li class="boxes default locaton_categories-greenhithe system_categories-system04"><h3>greenhithe System04</li>
<li class="boxes default locaton_categories-greenhithe system_categories-system04"><h3>greenhithe System04</li>
<li class="boxes default locaton_categories-london system_categories-system04"><h3>London System03</li>
</ul>
```

For some reason the code doesn't like divs? maybe harder to sort thought for the `filter` function
anyway if anyone comes across this problem and is stuck this simple jQuery code should do the trick :D
Today I learned I can love a jquery function thank you `filter()`